# How do you move the position of components like text in react native?

Tags: react-native

I'm coding in React Native and I want to move text positions and images without using bottom, top, left and right. These components only work for my screen only and will align incorrectly on other devices. Can someone show me how to move the components to custom positions on my app?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your question is probably too broad - questions typically have to be confined to one specific task.  It's also required to add debugging details - in your case that would be the nonworking code, and since it's a UI question, hopefully images of what's wrong and what you want to achieve.  See [ask] and how to make a [mcve] when you can.

Comment: Please attach your present code, screenshot of the issue and what exactly you need.

Comment: It depends on your use case. If you aren't trying to animate, and you only want the components to be placed in basic positions then [flexbox](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox) will do. If you need to animate then using [transform](https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/transforms) may be of use

Comment: For text components using the [textAlign](https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/text-style-props#textalign) prop may give better results

Answer (score 0):

without seeing your code or how you are using it my first suggestion would be to try and use padding. But here's a list of layout props in React Native https://reactnative.dev/docs/layout-props

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).